# A functional inequality involving Cos and ArcTan

Tags: inequality

I have been trying to prove the following inequality.
$-\dfrac{2}{\cos(p\pi)(1+x^{2})^{p}}+\dfrac{\cos\negthinspace\big(2p\arctan(x)\big)}{\cos(p\pi)}\geq-\dfrac{1}{2}\cos(p\pi)$ for $x>0$ and $1>p>\frac{1}{2}$.

3D plot shows that this inequality holds but I fail to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof.** Consider the original inequality
\begin{equation}
-\dfrac{2}{\cos(p\pi)(1+x^{2})^{p}}+\dfrac{\cos\negthinspace\big(2p\arctan(x)\big)}{\cos(p\pi)}\geq-\dfrac{1}{2}\cos(p\pi)
\quad\text{for}\ x\in[0,\infty)\ \text{and}\ p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},1).\notag
\end{equation}
We see that $-\frac{1}{\cos(p\pi)}>0$ for $p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},1)$, then we can rewrite this in the form
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{2}{(1+x^{2})^{p}}-\cos\negthinspace\big(2p\arctan(x)\big)\geq\dfrac{1}{2}\big[\negthinspace\cos(p\pi)\big]^{2}
\quad\text{for}\ x\in[0,\infty)\ \text{and}\ p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},1).\notag
\end{equation}
Substituting $t\mapsto\arctan(x)$, we get the modified inequality
\begin{equation}
2\big(\negthinspace\cos(t)\big)^{2p}-\cos(2pt)\geq\dfrac{1}{2}\big[\negthinspace\cos(p\pi)\big]^{2}
\quad\text{for}\ t\in[0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})\ \text{and}\ p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},1),\tag{A}
\end{equation}
which we will prove below.
Let us now denote by $f(t,p)$ the left-hand side of **(A)**.
Computing the partial derivatives, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial{}t}f(t,p)=&-2p\big[2\big(\negthinspace\cos(t)\big)^{2p-1}\sin(t)-\sin(2pt)\big]\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial{}p}f(t,p)=&2\big[2\big(\negthinspace\cos(t)\big)^{2p}\ln\negthinspace\big(\negthinspace\cos(t)\big)+t\sin(2pt)\big],
\end{aligned}\notag
\end{equation}
which yields by equating them to zero that
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    2\sin(t)&-1\\
    2\cos(t)\ln\negthinspace\big(\negthinspace\cos(t)\big)&t
  \end{array}
\right)}_{\boldsymbol{A}}
\underbrace{\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    \big(\negthinspace\cos(t)\big)^{2p-1} \\
    \sin(2pt)
  \end{array}
\right)}_{\boldsymbol{v}}
=
\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    0 \\
    0
  \end{array}
\right)
\quad\text{for}\ t\in(0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})\ \text{and}\ p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},1).\notag
\end{equation}
For $t\in(0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})$ and $p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},1)$,
$\boldsymbol{v}$ **cannot** be a trivial solution of the system, thus we must have $\det(\boldsymbol{A})=0$.
Denoting by $d(t)$ the determinant of $\boldsymbol{A}$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
d(t):=2\big[t\sin(t)+\negthinspace\cos(t)\ln\negthinspace\big(\negthinspace\cos(t)\big)\big]\quad\text{for}\ t\in(0,\tfrac{\pi}{2}),\notag
\end{equation}
we see that $d(0^{+})=0$ and $d^{\prime}(t)=2[t\cos(t)-\sin(t)\ln(\cos(t))]>0$ for $t\in(0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})$,
which shows that $d(t)>0$ for $t\in(0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})$.
Therefore, the function attains is extremal values on the borders.
Let us now consider in detail what happens on the borders.

> **1.** Let $0\leq{}t<\tfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $p\to\frac{1}{2}^{+}$.
>
> > **a.** First, let $0\leq{}t\leq\tfrac{\pi}{4}$, then $f(t,\tfrac{1}{2}^{+})=\cos(t)\geq\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\geq\frac{1}{2}\geq\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}(p\pi)$ for $p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},1)$.
> >
> > **b.** Next, let $\tfrac{\pi}{4}\leq{}t<\tfrac{\pi}{2}$.
> >         Define the auxiliary function $g(t,p):=f(t,p)-\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}(p\pi)$ for $t\in[\tfrac{\pi}{4},\tfrac{\pi}{2})$ and $p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},1)$.
> >         Obviously, $g_{t}(t,p)=f_{t}(t,p)$ for $t\in[\tfrac{\pi}{4},\tfrac{\pi}{2})$ and $p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},1)$.
> >         On one hand, we have $g_{t}(t,\tfrac{1}{2}^{+})=-\sin(t)\leq-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ for $t\in[\tfrac{\pi}{4},\tfrac{\pi}{2})$.
> >         On the other hand, similar to what we have done to show that $d$ is increasing, we can show that $g_{p}(t,\tfrac{1}{2}^{+})=2[t\sin(t)+2\cos(t)\ln(\cos(t))]\geq{}g_{p}(\tfrac{\pi}{4},\tfrac{1}{2}^{+})=\tfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{2}\ln(2)>0$ for $t\in[\tfrac{\pi}{4},\tfrac{\pi}{2})$.
> >         Since $g_{t}$ and $g_{p}$ are continuous on $[0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})\times(\tfrac{1}{2},1)$,
> >         there exists $\delta\in(0,\frac{1}{2})$ such that $g_{t}(t,p)<0$ and $g_{p}(t,p)>0$ for $t\in[\tfrac{\pi}{4},\tfrac{\pi}{2})$ and $p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2}+\delta)$.
> >         That is, $g(t,p)>g(\tfrac{\pi}{2}^{-},\tfrac{1}{2}^{+})=0$ for $t\in[\tfrac{\pi}{4},\tfrac{\pi}{2})$ and $p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2}+\delta)$.
> >         So $g(t,p)>0$ for $t\in[\tfrac{\pi}{4},\tfrac{\pi}{2})$, i.e., $f(t,p)>\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}(p\pi)$ for $t\in[\tfrac{\pi}{4},\tfrac{\pi}{2})$.
>
> In both subcases, we have $f(t,p)\geq\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}(p\pi)$ for $t\in(0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})$ and $p\in(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\delta)$,
>     where $\delta$ is defined in **Case 1(b)**.
>
> **2.** Let $0\leq{}t<\tfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $p\to1^{-}$.
>     For $t\in[0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})$ and $(\tfrac{1}{2},1)$,
>     define the auxiliary function $g(t,p)$ as in **Case 1(b)**.
>     We see that $g(t,1^{-})=\frac{1}{2}$ for $t\in[0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})$.
>     Since $g$ is continuous on $[0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})\times(\tfrac{1}{2},1)$,
>     there exists $\delta\in(0,\frac{1}{2})$ such that $g(t,p)>0$ for $t\in[0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})$ and $p\in(1-\delta,1)$.
>     This implies $f(t,p)>\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}(p\pi)$ for $t\in[0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})$ and $p\in(1-\delta,1)$.
>
> **3.** Let $t=0$ and $p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},1)$.
>     We see that $f(0,p)=1>\frac{1}{2}\geq\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}(p\pi)$ for $p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},1)$.
>
> **4.** Let $t\to\frac{\pi}{2}^{-}$ and $\tfrac{1}{2}<p<1$.
>     We obtain $f(\tfrac{\pi}{2}^{-},p)=-\cos(p\pi)$ for $p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},1)$.
>     Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})\times(\tfrac{1}{2},1)$ and $[-\cos(p\pi)]>\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}(p\pi)$ for $p\in(\tfrac{1}{2},1)$, there exists $\delta\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ such that $f(t,p)>\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}(p\pi)$ for $t\in(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-\delta,\tfrac{\pi}{2})$ and $p\in(\frac{1}{2},1)$.

Combining the cases above, we establish the inequality in **(A)**                                                            ■